# Connection refused with two microservices in Docker

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, microservices

I have two microservices and I want that one consumes of the other but I'm obtaining this mistake:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   GET request for "http://localhost:8080/testMicroservicio": Connection
>   refused (Connection refused); nested exception is
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)]
>   with root cause
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

However if I execute the url in the browser, it works perfectly but if a microservice wants to access to the other microservice, I have this mistake.

Does someone kown why?

I'm consuming with: RestTemplate

I put some of code:

```
@RestController
public class MicroServiceController {


    private final AddressService service;

    private static final String URL_API_INFO = "http://localhost:8080/testMicroservicio";

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.bernanetwork.web.controller.MicroServiceController");

    @Autowired
    public MicroServiceController(AddressService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/micro-service-test")
    public String consumidor() throws Exception {

        log.info("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        log.info("-------------------------Iniciando método consumidor------------------------------------");
        log.info("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        ResponseEntity <PruebasMicroservicio[]> response = restTemplate.getForObject(URL_API_INFO, PruebasMicroservicio[].class);

        Arrays.asList(response.getBody()).forEach(info -> log.info("---"+info));

        return "ok";
    }
```

These microservices are running in Docker

Thanks so much.

Comment: Please, specify how do you run containers?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to connect from one service to the other using `localhost`. This won't work as each container has it own IP and localhost will just point back to the caller of the request.

The stardard Docker way to connect containers, is to connect them to a Docker network.

```
docker network create mynet
docker run --network mynet --name container-1 ...
docker run --network mynet --name container-2 ...
```

Now container1 can communicate with container2 using `http://container-2:8080`.

Comment: Thanks so much, it was what I wanted. Also I saw after to run this command "docker network ls" that Docker's network is 172.17.0.1 and if I put this "http://172.17.0.1:8080/testMicroservicio" this works perfectly. In an enviroment of production, is it better to create a new network or to use default network "172.17.0.1"?

Comment: In production it is better to use docker swarm https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/. This has its own mechanisms for managing microservices. The container connection will be automatically established in docker swarm.

Comment: Thank you for this, It works fine, i did the mistake of call the server url with the netwok name, like this http://mynet:8080/someservice, then i realize that the name of the app was the part in the url http://container-1:8080/someservice.